# Printing same page multiple time

Tags: printing

When I'm using window.print() to print a page, it's printing same page multiple times, and also if the page is much longer, it's didn't printing the rest of the page, after printing the first portion of page.

I tried to debug and also use e.stopPropagation() on click event, but nothing happen